# Getting error while passing data of DJango list to javascript list

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, python-2.7

I have a python-Django list:

```
list_a = ['user_a', 'user_b']
```

Now i render it to a template with the following code:

```
extra_context = {
    'a': list_a
}
return direct_to_template(request, 'mytemplate.html', extra_context)
```

In my template, I wrote the following java script code to pass the  `list_a` Django-list to Js-list:

```
var user = [{% for i in user_list %}{{ i }}{% if forloop.last %}{%else%},{%endif%}{% endfor %}];
```

But when i open the template. It is showing following error (checked with Inspect element):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError : user_a is not defined
```

I tried to print the `user` variable reside in javascript using `Inspect Element`. It print the correct value i.e.

var user = [user_a, user_b]

I am not able to understand why is it happening :(

Comment: How is your Javascript supposed to know what 'user_a'  is?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't got you. I just checked these error with the Fire bug or Inspected element tools in Chrome

Comment: @AmitPal right, so `var user = [user_a, user_b]`, but what are `user_a` and `user_b`? Those inner names are not defined, hence the error.

Comment: @kojiro OH!I got that, But how should i defied that because it is dynamic list fetched from the database in python. I am newbie in Javascript. What should i do?

Would it be possible to pass these as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that i have found the mistake:

```
Update `var user = [{% for i in user_list %}{{ i }}{% if forloop.last %}{%else%},{%endif%}{% endfor %}];
```

to

```
var user = [{% for i in user_list %}"{{ i }}"{% if forloop.last %}{%else%},{%endif%}{% endfor %}];`
```

are giving me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can use

```
var user = {{user_list|safe}};
```

Using this template code, a python list defined as

```
user_list = ['te"s\'t1', 'test2'];
```

gives the following results when viewing javascript source

```
var user = ['te"s\'t1', 'test2'];
```

Whereas your original solution will give

```
var user = ["te&quot;s&#39;t1","test2"];
```

Which one you use really depends on what you intend to do with the usernames. Regardless of whether you use 'safe' or not in your template, it seems like the for and if statements in your template are a bit over-worked.